# IRC Bot not identifying with server - Connection hangs

Tags: c#, irc

When I try and connect to freenode using a simple IRC bot in C#, I get the following messages:

> :asimov.freenode.net NOTICE * :*** Looking up your hostname...
>
> :asimov.freenode.net NOTICE * :*** Checking Ident
>
> :asimov.freenode.net NOTICE * :*** Couldn't look up your hostname
>
> :asimov.freenode.net NOTICE * :*** No Ident response

And then after about 30 seconds, the program terminates.

I have tried sending the USER message before the NICK message, and also have tried manually appending the carriage return "\r\n" to the end of the line instead of specifying it in the StreamWriter options. Any ideas as to other things that might cause this behavior?

Here is my current code:

```
        socket = new TcpClient(host, port);
        socket.ReceiveBufferSize = 1024;
        Console.WriteLine("Connected");
        NetworkStream stream = socket.GetStream();
        reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        writer = new StreamWriter(stream) { NewLine = "\r\n", AutoFlush = true };
        writer.Write("NICK " + user);
        writer.Write("USER " + user + " 8 * :" + user);
        writer.Write("JOIN " + chan);
        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

        while(running)
        {
            line = reader.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
```

---

******Fixed - using .WriteLine fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: If you packetsniff this with Wireshark or similar, do you see your data actually being sent?  I suspect it is sitting in a buffer somewhere.

Comment: I think you should use .WriteLine not .Write if you want streamwriter to append \r\n to each line and flush it.

Comment: Try using `writer.WriteLine` to make sure the newline is appended at the end. Edit: Ninja'd by @Ravadre :)

Comment: @Harpyon: Yey, I became 1min ninja :-)

Comment: And you need to respond to PINGs. Else you'll get kicked very quickly. I don't remember if a PING can happen before registering.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, you are correct. After registering, there is a PING, and if you don't respond to it, you are disconnected.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, Harpyon: Actually, that PING after registering depends on the server - for example, Freenode doesn't use it to my knowledge, I was able to connect and was never pinged right away. However, foonetic, I believe, does implement it.

Comment: Your domain/servers/system must be setup to allow for reverse DNS.

Answer (score 3):

You're not flushing the buffer. use writer.Flush(); after each Write.

Example:

```
writer.Write("NICK {0}\r\n", user);
writer.Flush();
```

Or

```
writer.WriteLine("NICK {0}", user);
writer.Flush(); // Maybe here you will not need to flush because of the autoflush
```